# grep log file and write it on csv file

Tags: text-processing, grep, logs, csv

I do grep by codec file played to the user based on their call-id. There are 2 files played to the user/call-id. I am writing those grep output to the .csv file.
I used

```
grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log>>$CURRENTPATH/op2.csv
welcome1.g711u #(call_id1)
Announcementbui4.g711u #(call_id1)
welcome1.g711u #(call_id2)
Announcementbui4.g711u #(call_id2)
```

But i want output as

```
welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u #callid1
welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u #callid2
```

Comment: please add few lines of original input...

Comment: Are those comments actually in the output? Or is that just for our benefit. If the latter, pipe into `paste -d, - -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log; then
echo "Match found"
{ printf "%s," "$target_users"; grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log | sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'; }>>$CURRENTPATH/E41.csv
else
echo "Match not found"
{ printf "%s\n" "$target_users"; }>>$CURRENTPATH/E41.csv
fi
done
I got the output by iterating the above code with respect to call_id.
The required output that i got:
9188888881,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9177777772,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9166666663,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9155555554,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
9144444445,welcome1.g711u,Announcementbui4.g711u
Haxiel helped me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP "(?<=$START).*?(?=$END)" $IVRLOG$Progress_log>>$CURRENTPATH/op2.csv | 
while read line; do
grep "callid" | sed 's/()()//g'  #removing the brackets
done
```

you still might have to take care of the new spaces
Code not tested